# PHP - Return true or false depending on which button user clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, user-defined-functions

I am trying to make a PHP version of JavaScript's confirm() command:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    function confirm($title, $text) {
        $html = '<div id="alert" style="background-color:white; text-align:center; height:400px; width:300px; color:black; position:fixed; top: 0; left:50%; margin-left:-150px; border:1px solid black; box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px gray;">';
        $html = $html . '<h1 style="background-color:red; border-radius: 15px;">'. $title . '</h1>';
        $html = $html . '<span style="font-size: 20px;">The page at ' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ' says...</span><br><br>' . $text;
        $html = $html . '<br><br><button type="button" style="border-radius:25px; height:50px; width:100px; background-color:lightGray; border:1px solid black;" onclick="this.parentNode.style.display=\'none\'">OK</button>';
        $html = $html . '<button type="button" style="border-radius:25px; height:50px; width:100px; background-color:lightGray; border:1px solid black;" onclick="this.parentNode.style.display=\'none\'">Cancel</button>';
        echo $html;
    }
?>
```

How do I return true or false depending on which button the user clicked?

Comment: This can't be returned with php alone without submitting `form+button type=submit` or a javascript Ajax call

Comment: You function shows some html-code. Why should it return true or false?

Comment: Off-topic: to improve performance, use `echo` with commas instead of concatenating strings

Answer (score 0):

there's another less confusiong way of making your html

```
$html = '<div id="alert" style="background-color:white; text-align:center; height:400px; width:300px; color:black; position:fixed; top: 0; left:50%; margin-left:-150px; border:1px solid black; box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px gray;">';
$html.= '<h1 style="background-color:red; border-radius: 15px;">'. $title . '</h1>';
$html.= '<span style="font-size: 20px;">The page at ' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ' says...</span><br><br>' . $text;
$html.= '<br><br><button type="button" style="border-radius:25px; height:50px; width:100px; background-color:lightGray; border:1px solid black;" onclick="this.parentNode.style.display=\'none\'">OK</button>';
$html.= '<button type="button" style="border-radius:25px; height:50px; width:100px; background-color:lightGray; border:1px solid black;" onclick="this.parentNode.style.display=\'none\'">Cancel</button>';
echo $html;
```

EDIT - to get a value from a user in php, you must either use ajax, a form or the _GET protocol. Please note that once on screen, your html code isn't linked to any php script anymore. Your php function is executed during the call, while javascript functions are executed client side. you can't call a function from the page and use the return value in your php functions. what you can do is reload the page when the button is clicked, with your desired value in your url. note the onclick attribute.

```
<button type="button" style="border-radius:25px; height:50px; width:100px; background-color:lightGray; border:1px solid black;" onclick="window.location.href='yourscript.php?confirm=false'">Cancel</button>
<button type="button" style="border-radius:25px; height:50px; width:100px; background-color:lightGray; border:1px solid black;" onclick="window.location.href='yourscript.php?confirm=true'">OK</button>
```

also, your buttons could be replaced by anchors, like so (they can have the exact same styling as your buttons):

```
<a href="yourscript.php?confirm=false">cancel</a>
<a href="yourscript.php?confirm=true">OK</a>
```

with both you can retrieve the value like so in your php script:

```
$confirm = (isset($_GET['confirm']) ? $_GET['confirm'] : '');
```

Comment: I just want to have a return value in PHP. If they clicked "OK", return true. If they clicked "Cancel", return false.

Comment: How about just going out of php mode rather than echoing all that HTML? Then you don't need quotes or backslashes and you can just invoke php to echo variables... Like a template language.